# Publish AIR app including NativeProcess to .exe through Flash Pro

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to publish an AIR app to an .exe file from Flash Pro. My app includes the use of NativeProcess which means that my manifest file cannot include Desktop as a supported device and must include ExtendedDesktop. In the AIR settings I'm publishing as Windows installer.

I've tried publishing with Extended Desktop and Desktop selected, vice versa and both combinations but it seems to give me an error with NativeProcess which I don't get during testing, only when running the .exe file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this issue myself. It seems that I needed to add ffmpeg.exe to the included files to be packaged with the app itself.

Comment: Voted down the question and the answer. Will you please delete this whole waste of time that constitute a question that no one can answer : "seems to give me an error" and an answer that cannot in a million years help anyone.

Comment: It's a waste of a time answering my own question? So I should just leave the question unanswered instead right? The reason I wasn't specific with the error was because I wasn't actually seeing one, only a crash. And you're wrong because the answer helped me :)